# Parse CSV pull data and compare but not working. Java

Tags: java, parsing, csv, compare

I have a CSV file that I created. I am trying to pull the data and then run a check for certain data.

CSV file contents.

```
"12/05/14","Hay Square","10.00","10","","",""
"12/05/14","Hay Round","75","1","","",""
"12/05/14","Feed","12.50","10","","",""
"12/05/14","Feet","10","","trusty","",""
"12/05/14","Feed","4","5","","",""
"12/05/14","Wormer","12.75","","trusty","",""
"12/05/14","Feed","12","10","","",""
"","Feed","","","","",""
"12/05/14","Medicine","124.85","","sunny","",""
"12/05/14","Feet","90","","speedy","",""
```

I am using basic code and the print works fine to print what it finds but it simply will not compare VIA the if statement. I have searched everywhere and found nothing. Strange since I think this is commonly done.

As you can see in the code I am simply looking for "Feed" and want to print found. This is just test code for a greater project so this is very unfinished.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadCSV {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadCSV obj = new ReadCSV();
    obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {

    String csvFile = "c:/horse/horsespending.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            String test = country[1].toString();
            String tester = "\"Feed\"";
            System.out.println("check " + country[1]);
            if(test == tester){
            System.out.println("found");            
            } 
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
check "Purchase"
check "Hay Square"
check "Hay Round"
check "Feed"
check "Feet"
check "Feed"
check "Wormer"
check "Feed"
check "Feed"
check "Medicine"
check "Feet"
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't compare strings in java with `==`, instead use:

```
test.equals(tester)
```

Comment: Oh crude! I read that but wasn't thinking that is what I needed to do. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Because Strings are Objects type in java, use .equals() instead of == 
you are thinking about primitives!

```
testString.equals(toCompareToString) //boolean return
```

happy coding!
[Doc's to Java string lib](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)

Comment: Same as above. I read that but for some reason I didn't think that fit my case! Still learning, self taught here till college starts. And thanks for the link!

Comment: Forsure!!! glad I could've help. Same boat, So much to learn, Keep pressing forward friend!